# Codificar un timer para enviar un correo electrónico en dos horarios diarios específicos

Tags: c#, visual-studio, timer

Estoy con la creación de un servicio de windows que únicamente contiene *un timer*, el cual tiene como función ejecutar un método para enviar un correo. Está funcionando, pero mi problema es que cuando lo ejecuto, me envía el mail infinitas veces, como en bucle. No sé qué es lo que está mal en mi código. La idea es que lo envíe una sola vez.

```
public void OnStart()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

        timer1.AutoReset = true;

        timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);

        timer1.Start();



        //timer1.Stop();
    }

    private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Correo mail = new Correo();
            mail.enviarCorreo();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.save(this, ex);
        }
    }
```

Por otra parte, también quisiera que lo enviara a las 3am y a las 7am de manera diaria. Para ello había creado una variable "flag" de tipo booleano seteada en "false" para luego hacer dos condicionales comparando el horario actual con los horarios requeridos (3am / 7am), y si coinciden, entonces que setee la flag en "true". Por último había agregado un nuevo condicional para que si la flag estaba en true, llamara a mi método enviarCorreo... pero no funcionó. Así que lo borré (esta es la razón por la que escribo todo esto en vez de mostrar el código jeje). ¿Alguna idea de cómo hacer estas dos cosas?

**EDIT**

Probé con esto (los horarios son ficticios, para poder testear) pero tampoco funciona:

```
private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Correo mail = new Correo();

        bool flag = false;
        string horaFecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

        if (horaFecha == "11:53:00")
        {
            flag = true;
        }
        else if (horaFecha == "11:54:00")
        {
            flag = true;
        }

        try
        {
            if (flag == true)
            {
                mail.enviarCorreo();
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.save(this, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pues al timer lo estableces que cada segundo envie un correo, mmmhh despues de enviar el correo agrega un stop, y tambien agrega la verificacion de la hora es decir que digamos en lugar de enviar el correo hagas una funcion que verifique si se encuentra dentro del lapso de enviar correos si es asi entoces que envie el correo una vez enviado, se detiene el timer,

Comment: Ahí edité mi pregunta

Comment: Tu hora no es exacta al comparar por lo tanto horaFecha == "11:54:00" dificilmente se cumplira establecela dentro de un rango mayor que y menor que.

Comment: No me permite hacer una comparación dentro de un rango por problemas de tipado, y realmente no tengo mucha idea cómo hacer esto debido a que recién estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación. Si me pudieras guiar con un ejemplo en código me sería de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongamos que quieres enviar el correo en una hora especifica:

En este ejemplo no queremos que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo (evitamos estar checando cada minuto), sino 
que tomando en cuenta la hora de envio  contra la hora actual
el proceso se *duerme* el tiempo faltante para la ejecucion de envio.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //hora de envio
            var HoraEnvio = "11:00:00";
            var partesHoraEnvio = HoraEnvio.Split(new char[1] { ':' });

            var fechaHoraActual = DateTime.Now;
            var fechaHoraEnvio = new DateTime(fechaHoraActual.Year, fechaHoraActual.Month, fechaHoraActual.Day,
                       int.Parse(partesHoraEnvio[0]), int.Parse(partesHoraEnvio[1]), int.Parse(partesHoraEnvio[2]));
            TimeSpan ts;
            if (fechaHoraEnvio > fechaHoraActual)
                ts = fechaHoraEnvio - fechaHoraActual;
            else
            {
                fechaHoraEnvio = fechaHoraEnvio.AddDays(1);
                ts = fechaHoraEnvio - fechaHoraActual;
            }

            //espera TS tiempo y ejecuta la funcion.
            Task.Delay(ts).ContinueWith((x)=> EnviarCorreo());

            Console.Read();
        }

        static void EnviarCorreo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enviando correo...");
                //aqui la implemntacion del envio de correo
        }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha resultado, ya tengo mi servicio de windows funcionando :)

Answer (score -1):

Porque no pruebas hacerlo con un programador de tareas...

En windows puedes programar una tarea que ejecute tu codigo de enviar correo en el horario que le establezcas. te dejo un link https://www.genbeta.com/paso-a-paso/como-programar-tareas-en-windows-10.

Yo he realizado estos envios de correos con la ejecucion de un archivo PHP que envia mail, la tarea la programe con un cron en linux , dejo link https://www.redeszone.net/2017/01/09/utilizar-cron-crontab-linux-programar-tareas/

ademas he hecho cosas similares con ORACLE y su JOB nativo para ejecutar procedimientos almacenados.

Saludos

Comment: Es una excelente idea y probablemente sea lo que termine haciendo, pero aun así me gustaría aprender a hacerlo mediante código